# Add a parent directory to a git repositoy

Tags: git, history, version-control, repository

I have created a git repository for the C implementation of a program.

I am about to add a Matlab implementation and I would like to have a single repository with two subdirectories: one for the C and one for matlab.

Of course, I would like to keep the full history too!

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it in separate steps:

1. Create two new folders:  C and Matlab.
2. Move existing files from the current location into the C folder.
3. Start adding new files in the Matlab folder.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't thought of doing it this way!

Comment: @user36354 You may want to consider "*4. Run `git filter-branch` in order to pretend the files have always been in folder C.*" But this is a bit advanced and not really necessary (e.g. `git blame` can follow the history to the original location).

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614229/can-i-move-the-git-directory-for-a-repo-to-its-parent-directory/614254

Comment: That question is different - they are discussing how to combine two git repos into one.